# Dynamic graphQL query for Gatsby's gatsby-source-filesystem

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Is there a way to dynamically make a graphQL query when using Gatsby's `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin?

For example, I am looking to accomplish the following:

```
return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query chartQuery {
          all${fileKey}Json {          <------- Is this a thing?
            nodes {
              name
              data
              color
            }
          }
        }
      `}
```

Ideally, I would like to pass the fileName as a prop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Gatsby extracts GraphQL queries from your source code via static analysis before the code is executed. As such, you cannot assemble them via string manipulation functions or interpolation—they'll be extracted character for character before they're evaluated as JavaScript.

That said, there are myriad other approaches to achieve whatever end goal you're after. You can, for example, add a custom “resolver”—a field that takes arguments and calls a function you provide to synthesize data. Or you can create new nodes altogether, adding your local filesystem data to the Gatsby GraphQL server in a way that suits your needs. Or layer on top of it by pre-parsing your files before Gatsby does and inserting the correct type into your query before Gatsby has a chance to extract the query. And so on.

Comment: Ahhh yes I see that [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/#the-longer-answer) also. I also noticed [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/10482) ideally what I would want to do. 

my end goal is to be able to import (query) different files on the source system.  writing the same query over and over felt silly when the file name differs by two characters. 

I will look into the options you listed. Thank You!

Comment: Oh yeah in that case what you can do is create a GraphQL “Interface” that both types inherit from and then extend the Gatsby schema with it. That'll let you define a single GraphQL fragment that works on both types. The gatsby-plugin-sanity-image library does this with image types so that a single image fragment can be used for different GraphQL types that all happen to be images (full-disclosure: I'm the author). Might be worth referencing if you're looking for an example.